# Pandas `.loc` to multiple assignment causing reasonable slowdown

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have some code whereby I get a 10x speedup if I do **not** do multiple assignment, instead assigning across multiple rows e.g.

fast:

```
onset = pitch_df.loc[idx, 'onset_time']
dur = pitch_df.loc[idx, 'duration']
```

slow:

```
onset, dur = pitch_df.loc[idx, ['onset_time', 'duration']]
```

Is there an obvious reason for this, or is a more 'pandas' way of doing what I'm doing. I'd like to assign here to make my code more readable (i.e. I'd prefer not to write `.loc[...]` all over the place).

Here's a minimal working example (4x speedup here):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'onset_time': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
     'pitch': [61, 60, 60, 61, 60, 60],
     'duration': [4, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 2]}
).sort_values(['onset_time', 'pitch']).reset_index(drop=True)

def foo():
    for pitch, pitch_df in df.groupby('pitch'):
        for iloc in range(len(pitch_df)):
            idx = pitch_df.index[iloc]
            onset = pitch_df.loc[idx, 'onset_time']
            dur = pitch_df.loc[idx, 'duration']
            note_off = onset + dur

def bar():
    for pitch, pitch_df in df.groupby('pitch'):
        for iloc in range(len(pitch_df)):
            idx = pitch_df.index[iloc]
            onset, dur = pitch_df.loc[idx, ['onset_time', 'duration']]
            note_off = onset + dur

print(f'foo time: {timeit(foo, number=100)}')
print(f'bar time: {timeit(bar, number=100)}')
```

Image included below for easy reading.

[image]

Comment: You may also try `.at` instead of `.loc` to access single cells - should be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Poolka mentioned in a comment to your question, if you want scalar access `.at` has a smaller overhead. I'm no python expert, but here is a solution that may work for you:

```
def foo2():
    for pitch, pitch_df in df.groupby('pitch'):
        for iloc in range(len(pitch_df)):
            idx = pitch_df.index[iloc]
            onset, dur = (pitch_df.at[idx, x] for x in ('onset_time', 'duration'))
            note_off = onset + dur
```

```
foo time: 0.12590176300000167
bar time: 0.47044453300077294
foo2 time: 0.12269815599938738
```

Comment: That's grand, thank you. I've gone with separating over 2 lines (as opposed to list comprehension) just to make a touch clearer. Cheers.